# SSIS Error: The type of the value (Empty) being assigned to variable in foreach lop

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis

I have a simple SSIS task to get data from a Flat file and assign to variable and execute a data flow task to odbc source to put in a flat file destination

This are the steps I took:

1) First data flow task

- Create a variable of type Object.
- In Data Flow Task ,The source is a fla file source and the destination Recordset Destination

2)

- Pick your variable in VariableName dropdown.
- Create Foreach Loop Containter:
- Choose Foreach ADO Enumerator in Enumerator setting.
- As ADO object source variable pick your recordset variable from the dropdown list
- In Variable Mappings assign the value to the variable with index 0

3)

- In the foreach loop container I create a data glow task.
- The source is a ODBC source with the sql command. This is the query
  " SELECT ip,latitude,longitude,time FROM  "+ @[User::schema_1]+".visitors_location
  where countryid = 1
  and time between '20160901' and '20160930'
  "
- @[User::schema_1] is the variable that I matched in the foreach loop and I put the result in a flat file.

When I executed the package, I get this error

> The type of the value (Empty) being assigned to variable "XXX" 
>   differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type during execution.
>   Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

Comment: What do you mean by this?:   `•In Variable Mappings assign the value to the variable with index 0`   What is "the value" and what is "the variable"?   Sounds like you might be doing this wrong.   Which task are you getting the error on?